# Error when using SDL Web 8.5 deployer and clustered Redis setup

Tags: web8.5, deployer, redis

We are currently installing a web 8.5 environment, using Redis binary storage for the deployer microservice.

We have set up Redis using a cluster and two shards. However, when using this setup, we see the following error when we try to publish something

```
`redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot (command='RENAME', key='BINARY_STORAGE/Zip/tcm_0-3163212-66560.Content.zip')
       at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:117)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:196)
       at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.rename(BinaryJedis.java:287)
       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.redis.RedisStorageClient.lambda$rename$5(RedisStorageClient.java:60)
       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.redis.RedisStorageClient.execute(RedisStorageClient.java:92)
       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.redis.RedisStorageClient.rename(RedisStorageClient.java:60)
       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.binarystorage.redis.RedisBinaryStorage.renameTo(RedisBinaryStorage.java:200)
       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionUnzipStep.unzipAndMove(TridionUnzipStep.java:277)
       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionUnzipStep.process(TridionUnzipStep.java:159)
       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)`
```

When we don't use a clustered setup, but just use one redis shard, everything is working fine.

I was wondering if this kind of setup is not supported, or if we need some specific configuration/setup in our deployers if we want to enable this.